# WCF - Reuse types from another service reference

Tags: java, wcf

We have two webservice servers written in java:

- CoreService
- ExtensionService.

ExtensionService references CoreService and reuses types.

similarly, we have two client libraries:

- CoreClient with service reference to CoreService
- ExtensionClient with service reference to ExtensionService

**I would like ExtensionClient to reuse generated types from CoreClient**. If ExtensionClient generates its own "core" classes, I cannot reuse my business logic from CoreClient, because CoreClient works with different classes as ExtensionClient.

I'm able to write CoreClient datacontract manually. **How to force ExtensionClient to reuse classes from CoreClient**?

Comment: To clarify, you're writing a WCF client to call 2 java services?

Comment: @Tom: almost. my WCF ExtensionClient will call only the java ExtensionService. 

CoreClient could be named CoreLibrary. I need to share core library across multiple solutions. Contracts and business logic in CoreLibrary will be the same, but ExtensionService will change in each solution.

Answer (score 0):

Use svcutil.exe with the /r flag as described [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/youssefm/archive/2009/10/09/reusing-types-in-referenced-assemblies-with-svcutil-s-r-switch.aspx) to generate the client proxy for the ExtensionService, passing in the CoreService dll as an argument.

However, you need to be aware that svcutil.exe uses `DataContractSerializer` to help generate code and unfortunately this has a rather [strict set of rules](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733112.aspx) when it comes to parsing your service contracts.

So unless you service XSDs adhere to this set of rules svcutil.exe will switch to use the `XmlSerializer`, which doesn't support the /r flag (or re-use). Hence you will not be able to re-use types.

Comment: The DataContractSerializer incomplatibility was the reason why I was not able to reuse types.

I will try to customize CustomTool "WCF Proxy Generator" to skip generation of predefined set of proxy classes. Since they are generated in referenced assembly, it coudl work.

Comment: @Liero another option would be to manually edit your generated classes - this would be worth it as long as you don't anticipate the service contracts changing that often/

Comment: unfortunaltelly, they will change often. CoreService is meant to be shared between multiple solution and ExtensionService will extend the core based on client's requirements. ExtensionService will be different each time, so I would like to automate as much as possible.